# My array is only remembering last last element entered and histogram is not printing right

Tags: java, arrays, histogram

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RainRecording {

    private int choice;
    private Scanner input;
    private String site;
    private int days;
    private int daysCounter;
    private int[] rainRecorded;
    private int[] rainEntered;
    private float lattitude;
    private float longitude;
    private String message1;
    private String message2;
    private String message3;
    private String message4;
    private String message5;
    private String message6;

    // declare name of variable

    public RainRecording() {

        // declare value of variable

        this.message1 = "Site";
        this.message2 = "lattitude";
        this.message3 = "longitude";
        this.message4 = "Window";
        this.message5 = "days";
        this.message6 = ":";
        this.daysCounter = 0;
        this.input = new Scanner(System.in);
        mainMenu();

    }

    private void mainMenu() {
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("*** Rain Gauge Menu ***");
        System.out.println("  1: Create rain gauge");
        System.out.println("  2: Display rain gauge details");
        System.out.println("  3: Add daily rainfall measurement");
        System.out.println("  4: Display rainfall histogram");
        System.out.println("  5: Get maximum rainfall");
        System.out.println("  6: Check rainfall is below threshold");
        System.out.println("  7: Display anaylsis");
        System.out.println("  8: Exit");
        System.out.print("Please enter your selection: ");

        Chosen();

    }

    private void Chosen() {

        this.choice = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
        switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            createGauge();
            break;

        case 2:

            gaugeDetails();
            break;
        case 3:
            
            int i = 0;

            while( i < this.days || this.daysCounter == this.days) {
            
            if (this.daysCounter == this.days) {

                System.out.printf("Error - system full\n");
                mainMenu();

            }
            if (this.days < 1) {

                mainMenu();

            } else {        
                

                this.rainRecorded = new int[this.days];
                System.out.printf("Please enter rainfall for the current day:  ");
                rainRecorded[this.daysCounter] = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
                this.daysCounter++;
                this.rainEntered = new int[this.daysCounter];
                mainMenu();
            }
            
            i++;
            }
            break;
        case 4:
            System.out.printf("\n");
            displayHistogram();
            break;
        case 5:
            break;
        case 6:
            break;
        case 7:
            break;
        case 8:
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid input, try again");
            mainMenu();
        }

        while (choice != 8)
            ;

    }

    

    private void createGauge() {

        System.out.printf("\nPlease enter the name of the site :");
        this.site = input.nextLine();
        System.out.printf("Please enter the number of days to record :");
        this.days = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
        System.out.printf("Please enter the lattitute :");
        this.lattitude = Float.parseFloat(input.nextLine());
        System.out.printf("Please enter the longitude :");
        this.longitude = Float.parseFloat(input.nextLine());
        mainMenu();

    }

    private void gaugeDetails() {

        if (this.days > 0) {

            System.out.printf("%-9s %-3s %s \n", this.message1, this.message6, this.site);
            System.out.printf("%s %-3s % 09.4f\n", this.message2, this.message6, this.lattitude);
            System.out.printf("%s %-3s %9.4f\n", this.message3, this.message6, this.longitude);
            System.out.printf("%-9s %-3s %-2d%s \n", this.message4, this.message6, this.days, this.message5);

            mainMenu();

        } else {

            mainMenu();

        }

    }

    private void displayHistogram() {

        for (int i = 0; i < this.rainEntered.length; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < this.rainRecorded[i] - 1; j++) {

                System.out.print("*");

            }

            System.out.println(i);

        }

        System.out.print("");
        mainMenu();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        RainRecording objName;
        objName = new RainRecording();

    }

}
```

I guys i being struck on this for a couple of days in my switch statement in case 3  is where i create my elements to enter into my array , but in seems to only remember the last array entered when i print my histogram out in case 4 displayHistogram(); and this is where my histogram is printing wrong as well.
So to issues my array isn't recording property and histogram is printing wrong.
For example users chooses 3 days to enter and values are 10,20,30, and when i print histogram its prints this.

```
0    
1  
*****************************2
```

What i want this below , one * for ever ten mills of rain with index printed first.

```
0 *              
1 **  
2 **
```

Comment: You're creating a new instance of `this.rainRecorded = new int[this.days];` in your `while-loop`, so only the last one will ever been assigned

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the initialisation of `this.rainRecorded` to `createGauge` method and update the `displayHistogram` to print as required. You can try the following:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RainRecording {

  private int choice;
  private Scanner input;
  private String site;
  private int days;
  private int daysCounter;
  private int[] rainRecorded;
  private int[] rainEntered;
  private float lattitude;
  private float longitude;
  private String message1;
  private String message2;
  private String message3;
  private String message4;
  private String message5;
  private String message6;

  // declare name of variable

  public RainRecording() {

    // declare value of variable
    
    this.message1 = "Site";
    this.message2 = "lattitude";
    this.message3 = "longitude";
    this.message4 = "Window";
    this.message5 = "days";
    this.message6 = ":";
    this.daysCounter = 0;
    this.input = new Scanner(System.in);
    mainMenu();
  }

  private void mainMenu() {
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("*** Rain Gauge Menu ***");
    System.out.println("  1: Create rain gauge");
    System.out.println("  2: Display rain gauge details");
    System.out.println("  3: Add daily rainfall measurement");
    System.out.println("  4: Display rainfall histogram");
    System.out.println("  5: Get maximum rainfall");
    System.out.println("  6: Check rainfall is below threshold");
    System.out.println("  7: Display anaylsis");
    System.out.println("  8: Exit");
    System.out.print("Please enter your selection: ");
    Chosen();
  }

  private void Chosen() {
    this.choice = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
    switch (choice) {
      case 1:
        createGauge();
        break;
      case 2:
        gaugeDetails();
        break;
      case 3:
        int i = 0;
        while( i < this.days || this.daysCounter == this.days) {
          if (this.daysCounter == this.days) {
            System.out.printf("Error - system full\n");
            mainMenu();
          }
          if (this.days < 1) {

            mainMenu();

          } else {
            System.out.printf("Please enter rainfall for the current day:  ");
            rainRecorded[this.daysCounter] = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
            this.daysCounter++;
            this.rainEntered = new int[this.daysCounter];
            mainMenu();
          }

          i++;
        }
        break;
      case 4:
        System.out.printf("\n");
        displayHistogram();
        break;
      case 5:
        break;
      case 6:
        break;
      case 7:
        break;
      case 8:
        break;
      default:
        System.out.println("Invalid input, try again");
        mainMenu();
    }
    while (choice != 8)
      ;
  }



  private void createGauge() {
    System.out.printf("\nPlease enter the name of the site :");
    this.site = input.nextLine();
    System.out.printf("Please enter the number of days to record :");
    this.days = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
    this.rainRecorded = new int[this.days]; // move the array initialization here
    System.out.printf("Please enter the lattitute :");
    this.lattitude = Float.parseFloat(input.nextLine());
    System.out.printf("Please enter the longitude :");
    this.longitude = Float.parseFloat(input.nextLine());
    mainMenu();
  }

  private void gaugeDetails() {
    if (this.days > 0) {
      System.out.printf("%-9s %-3s %s \n", this.message1, this.message6, this.site);
      System.out.printf("%s %-3s % 09.4f\n", this.message2, this.message6, this.lattitude);
      System.out.printf("%s %-3s %9.4f\n", this.message3, this.message6, this.longitude);
      System.out.printf("%-9s %-3s %-2d%s \n", this.message4, this.message6, this.days, this.message5);
      mainMenu();
    } else {
      mainMenu();
    }
  }

  private void displayHistogram() {
    for (int i = 0; i < this.rainEntered.length; i++) {
      System.out.print(i + " ");
      for (int j = 0; j < this.rainRecorded[i] - 1; j += 10 ) {
        System.out.print("*");
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
    mainMenu();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    RainRecording objName;
    objName = new RainRecording();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, your codes a little bit over the place and I've had some issues trying to understand the basic intent, for example

```
private int[] rainRecorded;
private int[] rainEntered;
```

I'm not sure what the intention is for these two variables.  So in my example, I've discarded `rainEntered` for the time been.

So, your first problem starts here...

```
while( i < this.days || this.daysCounter == this.days) {

    if (this.daysCounter == this.days) {

        System.out.printf("Error - system full\n");
        mainMenu();

    }
    if (this.days < 1) {

        mainMenu();

    } else {        
        

        this.rainRecorded = new int[this.days];
        System.out.printf("Please enter rainfall for the current day:  ");
        rainRecorded[this.daysCounter] = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
        this.daysCounter++;
        this.rainEntered = new int[this.daysCounter];
        mainMenu();
    }
    
    i++;
}
```

First, I'd remove the need to for the two exit conditions, as it is going to make it more difficult to reasons about

Next, the checks for the validity of the data should be done outside of the loop and I'd also avoid calling `mainMenu` from within it, this is going to quickly put you in a strange place.

But, my main problem is with

```
this.rainRecorded = new int[this.days];
System.out.printf("Please enter rainfall for the current day:  ");
rainRecorded[this.daysCounter] = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
this.daysCounter++;
this.rainEntered = new int[this.daysCounter];
```

You keep creating new instances of both `this.rainRecorded` and `this.rainEntered`, meaning that each time the loop runs, you've lost anything that was previous entered.

So, in my "simplified" version, I modified it down to something like...

```
if (this.days < 1) {
    System.out.println("Invalid number of days");
    return;
}
if (this.daysCounter == this.days) {
    System.out.printf("Error - system full\n");
    return;
}

while (this.daysCounter < this.days) {
    System.out.printf("Please enter rainfall for the day " + (daysCounter + 1) + ":  ");
    rainRecorded[this.daysCounter] = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
    this.daysCounter++;
}
```

I then simplified the histogram workflow as well, but I'm still trying to get my head around what `rainEntered` is suppose to do...

```
private void displayHistogram() {
    for (int amount : rainRecorded) {
        for (int count = 0; count < amount; count++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println(" " + amount);
    }
}
```

One last thing I also did, was to remove all the calls to `mainMenu` and instead relied on a simple `do-while` loop to reprint the menu each time it returned from `Chosen` method

```
private void mainMenu() {
    do {
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("*** Rain Gauge Menu ***");
        System.out.println("  1: Create rain gauge");
        System.out.println("  2: Display rain gauge details");
        System.out.println("  3: Add daily rainfall measurement");
        System.out.println("  4: Display rainfall histogram");
        System.out.println("  5: Get maximum rainfall");
        System.out.println("  6: Check rainfall is below threshold");
        System.out.println("  7: Display anaylsis");
        System.out.println("  8: Exit");
        System.out.print("Please enter your selection: ");

        Chosen();
    } while (shouldContinue);
}
```

This simplifies the workflow, as it's easier to reason about where you are at any point in the execution of the program, instead of wondering why when, under some condition, when you chose something from the menu, you end up in some other part of the program instead.

## Example

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RainRecording {

    private int choice;
    private Scanner input;
    private String site;
    private int days;
    private int daysCounter;
    private int[] rainRecorded;
    //private int[] rainEntered;
    private float lattitude;
    private float longitude;
    private String message1;
    private String message2;
    private String message3;
    private String message4;
    private String message5;
    private String message6;

    private boolean shouldContinue = true;

    // declare name of variable

    public RainRecording() {

        // declare value of variable

        this.message1 = "Site";
        this.message2 = "lattitude";
        this.message3 = "longitude";
        this.message4 = "Window";
        this.message5 = "days";
        this.message6 = ":";
        this.daysCounter = 0;
        this.input = new Scanner(System.in);
        mainMenu();

    }

    private void mainMenu() {
        do {
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("*** Rain Gauge Menu ***");
            System.out.println("  1: Create rain gauge");
            System.out.println("  2: Display rain gauge details");
            System.out.println("  3: Add daily rainfall measurement");
            System.out.println("  4: Display rainfall histogram");
            System.out.println("  5: Get maximum rainfall");
            System.out.println("  6: Check rainfall is below threshold");
            System.out.println("  7: Display anaylsis");
            System.out.println("  8: Exit");
            System.out.print("Please enter your selection: ");

            Chosen();
        } while (shouldContinue);
    }

    private void Chosen() {

        this.choice = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                createGauge();
                break;

            case 2:
                gaugeDetails();
                break;
            case 3:

    if (this.days < 1) {
        System.out.println("Invalid number of days");
        return;
    }
    if (this.daysCounter == this.days) {
        System.out.printf("Error - system full\n");
        return;
    }

    while (this.daysCounter < this.days) {
        System.out.printf("Please enter rainfall for the day " + (daysCounter + 1) + ":  ");
        rainRecorded[this.daysCounter] = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
        this.daysCounter++;
    }
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.printf("\n");
                displayHistogram();
                break;
            case 5:
                break;
            case 6:
                break;
            case 7:
                break;
            case 8: shouldContinue = false;
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid input, try again");
        }

    }



    private void createGauge() {
        System.out.printf("\nPlease enter the name of the site :");
        this.site = input.nextLine();
        System.out.printf("Please enter the number of days to record :");
        this.days = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
        System.out.printf("Please enter the lattitute :");
        this.lattitude = Float.parseFloat(input.nextLine());
        System.out.printf("Please enter the longitude :");
        this.longitude = Float.parseFloat(input.nextLine());

        if (days > 0) {
            this.rainRecorded = new int[this.days];
        }
    }

    private void gaugeDetails() {

        if (this.days > 0) {

            System.out.printf("%-9s %-3s %s \n", this.message1, this.message6, this.site);
            System.out.printf("%s %-3s % 09.4f\n", this.message2, this.message6, this.lattitude);
            System.out.printf("%s %-3s %9.4f\n", this.message3, this.message6, this.longitude);
            System.out.printf("%-9s %-3s %-2d%s \n", this.message4, this.message6, this.days, this.message5);

        }

    }

    private void displayHistogram() {
        for (int amount : rainRecorded) {
            for (int count = 0; count < amount; count++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println(" " + amount);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        RainRecording objName;
        objName = new RainRecording();
    }
}
```

Now, if `rainEntered` is suppose to be some kind of compounding array, where it allows you to record multiple days of rain over different periods, you might consider using a multi-dimensional array instead, so you could `n` periods and each period could have `n` days of rain...